# Envelopes created with the C# SDK are not showing in Docusign eSignature Admin

Tags: c#, jwt, docusignapi, envelope

I am trying to use the docusign C# SDK to create and an envelope with a document to be signed. I have got it to a point where from my app I can create the envelopeDefinition, create the envelope using the envelopeDefinition then create a RecipientViewRequest and use that RecipientViewRequest to make the ViewUrl and then navigate to that Url to sign the document in the envelope just like how the embedded signing ceremony is done in the quick start example. However I have now noticed that I can't actually see any of the envelopes that have been sent and then signed, there are no envelopes listed on the manage page on the Docusign eSignature site.

I was wondering if this has anything to do with being in the Developer Environment or not but when I run the quick start project, the created envelope shows in Docusign eSignature as "waiting for others" and then as "completed" when I sign the document.

I have compared my code against the code provided in the quick start project from the Docusign Developer site and the only difference is the fact that the embedded signing example from docusign uses the Auth Code Grant flow whereas I am currently using the JWT flow. Other than that I am creating the Envelope that same way that the quick start example is.

Comment: ***Welcome! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good work on getting as far as you have!

The envelopes you're creating belong to the user your code is authenticating as. -- the `userId` you're using for your JWT flow.

If you log into the DocuSign web app as the same user, you should see your envelopes. -- Same as the envelopes you're creating with the quick start app.

Comment: Thank you, that makes total sense! I have changed the userId to my accounts userId instead of my colleagues Id that was in our config settings and I can now see the envelopes being created by my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple accounts to DocuSign, or if you have both a developer and a production account, you may be confusing your DocuSign accounts.

If you go to https://account.docusign.com that is different than going to https://account-d.docusign.com, the -d for the developer environment, and the former URL is for production, and the envelopes are not shared between the two sites even if you have the same username and password.

Or, you could have two accounts with the same username/password in the same environment. In that case in the right-hand top of the screen in the menu you open there, you will see a "Switch Account" option enabling you to switch to the other acccount.

You will find your envelopes in one of these places.